# Where can I find the Latitude__s and Longitude__s fields Or how to capture Latitude__s and Longitude__s via api

Tags: geolocation

I am new in implementing and using the location fields .

Need to know where can I find the Latitude__s and Longitude__s fields? Trying to bring this data from salesforce but cannot find what object they are in. Also how they are implemented and used.

Comment: are you planning to search object/search field metadata to find these types of fields?

Comment: If you create field with type Location called MyCoords__c, then to get lat/lon you can use MyCoords__Latitude__s and MyCoords__Longitude__s. More info about usage here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important to know is that they are compound fields, part of [custom geolocation fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm) or the [address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) fields.

This is also how you'll find them in the SOAP API:

Address field:

```
<element name="BillingAddress" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:address"/>
<element name="BillingCity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingCountry" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingCountryCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingGeocodeAccuracy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingLatitude" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
<element name="BillingLongitude" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
<element name="BillingPostalCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingState" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingStateCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="BillingStreet" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Custom GeoLocation field:

```
<element name="sdry__GeoCoordinates__Latitude__s" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
<element name="sdry__GeoCoordinates__Longitude__s" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
<element name="sdry__GeoCoordinates__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:location"/>
```

Rest API returns the same combination of fields.